# Посоветуйте литературу о структуре .o файлов и ELF формате

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, где я моге найти информацию о структуре obj файла?

Меня интересуют байты содержащиеся в объектом файле после компиляции с помощью nasm, которые не имеют прямого отношения к коду программы.

Код программы

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Команда компиляции

```
nasm ex4.s -f elf64 -o ex4.o
```

objdump

```
ex4.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
   5:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
   a:   0f 05                   syscall
```

hexdump

```
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.ELF............|
00000010  01 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..>.............|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........@.......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  00 00 40 00 05 00 02 00  |....@.....@.....|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000080  01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  80 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000a0  0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000b0  10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000c0  07 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  90 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000e0  21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |!...............|
000000f0  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000100  11 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  c0 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  |`...............|
00000130  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  19 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  20 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........ .......|
00000160  0e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  b8 3c 00 00 00 bf 00 00  00 00 0f 05 00 00 00 00  |.<..............|
00000190  00 2e 74 65 78 74 00 2e  73 68 73 74 72 74 61 62  |..text..shstrtab|
000001a0  00 2e 73 79 6d 74 61 62  00 2e 73 74 72 74 61 62  |..symtab..strtab|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 04 00 f1 ff  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 03 00 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 10 00 01 00  |................|
00000210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000220  00 65 78 34 2e 73 00 5f  73 74 61 72 74 00 00 00  |.ex4.s._start...|
00000230
```

Из выше приведенного видно, что код программы занимает только байты

```
b8 3c 00 00 00 bf 00 00  00 00 0f 05
```

При этом hexdump и objdump принадлежат объектному файлу (без байтов добавляемых линковщиком).

Хотелось бы узнать что именно означают оставшиеся байты и если есть в публичном доступе, то получить информацию о структуре описывающей формат объектных файлов.

Comment: Это [ELF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). Начинать читать можно с вики, затем анвики, а затем все ссылки внизу обеих страниц.

Comment: http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf

Comment: Может быть кто-то может подкинуть ссылку на документацию по libelf из пакета elfutils?